# zsh shell prompt showing unrecognised number

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, macos-sierra

When I open a terminal window I now get this prompt in my zsh shell.

```
Last login: Wed Mar 11 15:35:53 on ttys000
You have new mail.
167~(:|✔) %
```

I thought it may have been a user ID, however it is not listed here:

```
167~(:|✔) % id
uid=502(crmpicco) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),400(com.apple.access_remote_ae),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
```

This is my `~/.zshrc` which has had no recent changes.

https://gist.github.com/crmpicco/6c05f4a051ac650909fe6b636fbc7324

Where is that random "167" coming from?

Comment: Try `echo $PS1` to see what it is.

Comment: Could it be that this is your hostname? The `%m` in your `PROMPT` variable expands to the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following line in your `.zshrc`:

```
PROMPT='%B%m%~%b$(git_super_status) %# '
```

You can read the meaning of the escape variables in `man zshmisc` in the section "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES". `%B` changes to boldface mode, and `%m` outputs the hostname (up to the first `.`). So I believe the 167 is your hostname.

Comment: Thank you. This helped too https://zsh-prompt-generator.site/